Why we get double roots for $x,y,z$ in solving $x+\frac{1}{y}=4, y+ \frac{1}{z} =1, z+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{7}{3}$?
This is a problem from $2000$ AMC $12$-Problem $20:

If $x,y,$ and $z$ are positive numbers satisfying
$x + \frac{1}{y} = 4,\qquad y + \frac{1}{z} = 1, \qquad \text{and} \qquad z + \frac{1}{x} = \frac{7}{3}$
Then what is the value of $xyz$?

I understood the provided solutions in the linked page. But my question is regarding a fact that I found interesting:
Using the the solution$2$'s approach in the linked page, and starting from different equations I got:
Starting from the first equation:
$$4=x+\frac1y=x+\frac1{1-\dfrac1z}=x+\frac1{1-\dfrac1{\dfrac7{3}-\dfrac1x}}$$Simplifying this leads to, $$x+\dfrac{7x-3}{4x-3}=4\Rightarrow(2x-3)^2=0$$
Starting from the second equation:
$$1=y+\frac1z=y+\dfrac1{\dfrac73-\dfrac1x}=y+\dfrac1{\dfrac73-\dfrac1{4-\dfrac1y}}$$
Simplifying it leads to, $$y+\dfrac{12y-3}{25y-7}=1\Rightarrow (5y-2)^2=0$$
Starting from the third equation:
$$\frac73=z+\frac1x=z+\dfrac1{4-\dfrac1y}=z+\dfrac1{4-\dfrac1{1-\dfrac1z}}$$
It leads to:
$$z+\dfrac{z-1}{3z-4}=\dfrac73\Rightarrow (3z-5)^2=0$$

As you can see, we got double roots for each of $x$, $y$, and $z$. I'm wondering why this happens? Is there something special about this specific system of the equations or we would get double roots for other system of equations say
$$ \begin{cases} {x+\frac1y=a} \\ {y+\frac1z=b} \\ {z+\frac1x=c} \end{cases}   $$
Assuming $a,b,c,x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$. If we get double roots for this specific triple $(a,b,c)=(4,1,\frac73)$, what criteria is  needed to get double roots?

Here is my calculation for the general form:
\begin{cases} {x+\dfrac{cx-1}{(bc-1)x-b}=a} \\ {y+\dfrac{ay-1}{(ac-1)y-c}=b} \\ {z+\dfrac{bz-1}{(ab-1)z-a}=c} \end{cases}
Simplifying it leads to:
\begin{cases} {(1-bc)x^2+(abc+b-a-c)x+(1-ab)=0} \\ {(1-ac)y^2+(abc+c-a-b)y+(1-bc)=0} \\ {(1-ab)z^2+(abc+a-b-c)z+(1-ac)=0} \end{cases}
From here we should put $\Delta=0$ for each equation. For the simplicity let $P=abc$ and $S=a+b+c$,
\begin{cases} {(1-\dfrac{P}a)x^2+(P-S+2b)x+(1-\dfrac{P}c)=0} \\ {(1-\dfrac{P}b)x^2+(P-S+2c)x+(1-\dfrac{P}a)=0} \\ {(1-\dfrac{P}c)x^2+(P-S+2a)x+(1-\dfrac{P}b)=0} \end{cases}
Nevertheless, it seems we wouldn't get a good-looking condition on $a,b,c$.

You could just do the same computation for general $a,b,c$. What do you obtain?

@DietrichBurde I haven't thought about that thanks for the hint.

For a quadratic equation $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$, there is a formula for double roots in terms of $A,B,C$, namely $\Delta=B^2-4AC=0$. In your case, this is always satisfied. Indeed,
$$
\Delta=(abc+b-a-c)^2-4(1-bc)(1-ab)=0,
$$
for your first equation. The same holds for the other two equations.

And to answer OP's question of "what criteria is needed", we can further factorize it into $(abc-a-b-c-2)(abc-a-b-c+2) = 0$. This symmetry also explains why if one discriminant is 0, then all are 0. $\quad$ And indeed, $ 4 \cdot 1 \cdot 7/3 - 4 -1 - 7/3 - 2 = 0 $.

@CalvinLin Thanks for the insight. I was actually looking for this factorization: $(abc-a-b-c-2)(abc-a-b-c+2) = 0$. Since, using the first solution of the AoPS page (linked in my post) leads to $xyz$ is unique iff $abc-(a+b+c)=\pm2$. By the way would you elaborate how you obtained this factorization?

(Wolfram is the easiest way lol.)  Well, I knew we wanted this cyclic version to turn into something very symmetric, and we didn't have that many options, so I first looked at how to modify the first square into $(abc-a-b-c)^2$, which left $4b(abc-a-c)$. That canceled out significantly with the second term, leaving $-4$, so we can factorize it as $(abc-a-b-c \pm 2)$.

@CalvinLin It's very good! I marked this answer as an accepted one because, it answered my question on finding a good-looking condition on $a,b,c$.
